# Load Data infile database access Permissions / privileges

Tags: mysql, file-upload, privileges

I need to load a CSV file from client machine to MySQL server database. 
I am trying LOAD DATA INFILE.

My confusion is regarding ACCESS PERMISSIONs required to use 
- LOAD DATA INFILE 
- LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Earlier I believed that I need FILE privilege to use both of them.

I came across this line in mysql documentation :

- when reading text files located on the server, the files must either reside in the database directory or be readable by all. Also, to use LOAD DATA INFILE on server files, you must have the FILE privilege. See Section 6.2.1, “Privileges Provided by MySQL”. For non-LOCAL load operations, if the secure_file_priv system variable is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory.

Looking at this, I got confused.

Do I need FILE privilege to load FILE from client machine using LOCAL option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- We do not need `FILE` privilege to LOAD data-file from a remote machine to MySQL Server. We need `--local-infile` option on Client machine enabled for that.
- We need `FILE` privilege when we are trying to LOAD a data-file which is present on MySQL server. Additionally, mysql demon should also have access to `READ` from directory where data-file is placed.